# Integration of custom model with Watson Discovery - entity normalisation

Tags: watson-discovery

My question relates to integration of a custom model with Watson Discovery in respect to entity normalization. Watson Discovery provides entity normalization capability but the feature is only available with WKS model as mentioned here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/discovery-auxiliary.html#normalizing-entities
*Note: Entity normalization is available only when you use the Discovery service with a custom model generated by Watson Knowledge Studio, as described in Integrating with IBM Watson™ Knowledge Studio.*

The document above also mentions that canonical names are derived from a **public dictionary**. I am trying to find out what is the source of that dictionary. Is this something that WKS model exposes?